# How can i get it to increment and print whenever i press the key, not just once?

Tags: python, while-loop, keyboard-python

With the below program, whenever I press the "a" key, the `keypresses` variable increments by `1`. The problem is, if I don't immediately let go fo the key, the `keypresses` variable continues to increment by `1`.

How can I get it to increment *(and print)* whenever I press the key, ignoring the hold aspect?

```
import keyboard
keypresses = 0
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
        keypresses = keypresses +1
        print(keypresses)   
        print("A Key Pressed")
        break
```

Comment: Did you mean to break out of the loop when `a` is pressed?

Comment: not really, i did so i dont get constantly print values non stop

Comment: Your comment "so i dont get constantly print values non stop" seems to conflict with your question "How can i get it to increment and print whenever i press the key, not just once?" What is your desired outcome?

Comment: My desire outcome is to print whenever i press the key, and count increments.

Comment: What is "the key"? Are you trying to print every single key that is pressed but only count the number of times that `a` is pressed?

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you want it so that pressing and holding only prints once *(not indefinitely)*, and it will print again as long as the `a` key is released and pressed again.

Define a variable, `pressing`, to get if the key is still being pressed, or released:

```
import keyboard

keypresses = 0
pressing = False

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
        if not pressing:
            pressing = True
            keypresses = keypresses +1
            print(keypresses)   
            print("A Key Pressed")
    else:
        pressing = False
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd remove the `break` statement.
On the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)  you can see that `break` exits the innermost `for`/`while` loop, in your case the that loop would be the

```
while True:
```

Answer (score 1):

if you remove the break statement like this:

```py
import keyboard
keypresses = 0
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
        keypresses = keypresses +1
        print(keypresses)   
        print("A Key Pressed")
    break
```

this does not work, and when you run it, it is instantly finished the while cycle.
because the `keyboard.is_pressed` only detect **now**
and precisely because of this, which caused too many cpu

if you are in windows , you can use `msvcrt` to instead :-)